# Circle construction

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I am stuck on this construction:

"Show how to construct a circle to pass through two given points and to cut a given circle so that the common chord is of given length".

Any clues?

Comment: @String I think that the premises are: a circle, a lenght of chord, two external points.

Comment: @Martigan: Ah OK, I misread it.

Comment: By "construct", do you mean using ruler and compass? Algebraically, it should not be too hard to determine the center of the circle.

Comment: The question is about construction with instruments but it would help if there was an algebraic method for determining a centre with the given information.  That would, after all, form the "proof" of the construction.

Answer (score 2):

OK..I think I have the answer...phew..

Let us call the given points A,B and the given chord length = CD with the centre of the given circle O.  If it helps in understanding in my answer I have drawn the given circle to the left and placed A, B to the right of it around the 2 o'clock position.

Join AB..construct perpendicular bisector of AB (XY).  Centre of desired circle therefore lies on XY.

Draw any circle through A, B, with centre on XY to cut given circle at C', D' .  Produce D'C' to meet BA produced at P.

Construct tangent to given circle PT.

Construct square with side equal to PT.  Reduce constructed square to a rectangle with sides equal to PD, CD (CD is given so is known therefore PD can be constructed)

With centre P cut given circle with arc = PD at point D.  Join PD.  PD cuts given circle again at C giving us the desired common chord CD.  Bisect CD to intersect XY giving us centre of desired circle..